# How to fix Uninitialized Constant in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting a:

> uninitialized constant ProfilesController::EUserPofile

error when trying to:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #@profiles = EUserProfile.all
  end

  def preview
    @profiles = EUserPofile.all
  end

end
```

it works fine for index but for preview it crashes.

here is my route file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  get 'welcome', to: 'pages#home'
  get 'profiles', to: 'profiles#index'
  get 'login', to: 'login#login'

  resources :profiles do
    get 'preview', on: :member
  end

end
```

Comment: Sure its not `EUserProfile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo: `EUserPofile` -> `EUserProfile`